numpy error in cross() with dtype=object arrays
import numpy as np
u = np.array([1, 2, -1], dtype=object)
v = np.array([-1, 1, 0], dtype=object)
np.cross(u, v)

fails with numpy._core._exceptions._UFuncOutputCastingError: Cannot cast ufunc 'multiply' output from dtype('O') to dtype('int64') with casting rule 'same_kind'.
np.dot(u, v) works as expected.
Using dtype=object because calculations with actual data will overflow int64 and give incorrect results (without warning). The actual values are integers with about 15 significant digits (50 binary digits).
One workaround is to make all values Decimals:
u = np.array(list(map(Decimal, [1, 2, -1])))
v = np.array(list(map(Decimal, [-1, 1, 0])))
np.cross(u, v)

Is there a better workaround using numpy?

Note that there is no performance benefit of using Numpy with objects. In fact, it is actually generally slower than lists. Some Numpy function might not works with objects. AFAIK this is for example the case of linear-algebra functions.

If Decimal works, then you can just wrap your own integer in a class and certainly get the expected behaviour.

The error line (show the full traceback please!) is 1669 multiply(a0, b2, out=tmp).  It looks like it creates tmp as a int32 array, not an O dtype.  I haven't quite figured out how it's setting the result dtype.  It's using np.multiply(u,v, out) format instead of simple u*v in order to reuse result arrays and save some time.

With simple arrays like this (3,), you should be able to write your cross with a * multiplies.  You don't need the extra axes baggage, and the abilty to handle (2,) shapes.  Nor are you worried about maximizing speed,

"The actual values are integers with about 15 significant digits (50 binary digits)." Note that 64-bit floating point numbers have about 15 significant digits. So it seems like you could use float64 instead.

There is a line in np.cross that reads tmp = np.array(a2 * b1).  It should be tmp = np.array(a2 * b1, dtype=cp.dtype), preserving the dtype that had previously been chosen for the result.  That needs to be raised as a bug/issue.

Making u,v 2d arrays instead of 1d also gets around this bug.

@JérômeRichard, there's a bug in np.cross that only affects 1d object dtype arrays of Python scalars.  It allows a int32 dtype temporary array to creap into the calculation.

There's a block in np.cross that lets a temporary result array become int32.
That block with my correction is:
 ...:         assert a.shape[-1] == 3
 ...:         if b.shape[-1] == 3:
 ...:             # cp0 = a1 * b2 - a2 * b1
 ...:             # cp1 = a2 * b0 - a0 * b2
 ...:             # cp2 = a0 * b1 - a1 * b0
 ...:             np.multiply(a1, b2, out=cp0)
 ...:             tmp = np.array(a2 * b1, dtype=cp.dtype) # correct dtype
 ...:             print(tmp,tmp.dtype, cp0.dtype)
 ...:             cp0 -= tmp
 ...:             np.multiply(a2, b0, out=cp1)
 ...:             np.multiply(a0, b2, out=tmp)
 ...:             cp1 -= tmp
 ...:             np.multiply(a0, b1, out=cp2)
 ...:             np.multiply(a1, b0, out=tmp)
 ...:             cp2 -= tmp

With your object dtype arrays:
In [384]: u = np.array([1, 2, -1], dtype=object)
     ...: v = np.array([-1, 1, 0], dtype=object)

np.cross raises an error involving this tmp:
In [385]: np.cross(u,v)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UFuncTypeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[385], line 1
----> 1 np.cross(u,v)

File <__array_function__ internals>:200, in cross(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py:1669, in cross(a, b, axisa, axisb, axisc, axis)
   1667 cp0 -= tmp
   1668 multiply(a2, b0, out=cp1)
-> 1669 multiply(a0, b2, out=tmp)
   1670 cp1 -= tmp
   1671 multiply(a0, b1, out=cp2)

UFuncTypeError: Cannot cast ufunc 'multiply' output from dtype('O') to dtype('int32') with casting rule 'same_kind'

cp has previously been created as the return array, taking into account the dtypes of the inputs.
In [387]: mycross(u,v)
object
-1 object object
Out[387]: array([1, 1, 3], dtype=object)

a1 and b2 are elements (columns actually) of a and b, e.g. a1=a[...,0].
The selection is still object dtype, but the product is not:
In [406]: u[...,0]
Out[406]: array(1, dtype=object)
In [407]: np.array(u[...,0]*v[...,1])
Out[407]: array(1)

So clearly there's a bug in np.cross, and possibly something in the product of object dtype arrays when the result is scalar.
If u,v are 2d arrays, e.g. (1,3), instead of (3,), np.cross works:
In [408]: np.cross(u[None],v[None])
Out[408]: array([[1, 1, 3]], dtype=object)


Thank you for your expert help. In the end, I used int types with dtype=object and up-dimensioned before taking cross product. Easy to back out when numpy fixed, and without performance penalty.

Bug filed: link
